# Rounded UIButton with size that fits its title

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'd like to have a rounded UIButton whose size will be constrained by its title.
This button will be placed in a Horizontal stack view, with a preceding text. I want the size of the button to be fixed while the size of the preceding text is only constrained by the space available alongside the button.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
UIStackView textAndDoneButtonStackView = new UIStackView
{
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal,
    Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.Fill,
    Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center,
    Spacing = 10
};

// Create the appropriate control for this habit                
UIView habitTitleView = CreateControlForHabit(habitTitle, kv.Value.workout, workoutName);
textAndDoneButtonStackView.AddArrangedSubview(habitTitleView);

// Add the done button
UIButton doneButton = CreateDoneButton(healthy_green);
habitIdDoneButtonId[kv.Value.id] = (int)doneButton.Tag;

textAndDoneButtonStackView.AddArrangedSubview(doneButton);
```

and

```
CreateControlForHabit(...)
{
    UILabel uIHabitTitle = new UILabel { TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false };
    uIHabitTitle.Text = habitTitle;
    return uIHabitTitle;
}
```

then

```
private static UIButton CreateDoneButton(UIColor healthy_green)
{
    // Add the done button

    var doneButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
    doneButton.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    doneButton.SetTitle(Utilities.GetLocalizedString("habit_done_button_text"), UIControlState.Normal);
    doneButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
    doneButton.BackgroundColor = healthy_green; // Healthy Green
    doneButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;
    doneButton.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
    doneButton.ContentEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10f, bottom: 0, right: 10f);

    doneButton.Tag = doneButton.GenerateViewTag();

    // View is hidden by default
    doneButton.Hidden = true;

    return doneButton;
}
```

My problem is that I want a rounded button and I can't cast the result of UIButton.FromType() to a custom class that would override IntrinsicContentSize.

What are the options available here to fix the size of this rounded button?

Comment: Can you please have a try with `doneButton.SizeToFit();`?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I've tried it but the stack view seems to changed it because it "seems" this has no effect.

Comment: Is the preceding text fixed? Then you can calculate the button size by the text and set it.

Comment: This is a great resource https://makeapppie.com/2018/10/17/make-round-buttons-and-uiviews/